# java compilation error for bitwise "OR" for double type

Tags: java

I have some double numbers that I need to apply '|', but I am getting a compilation error like the following.

```
double x1 = -95.1274171592;
double x2 = -1518.4102607642;
double x3 = -346.63776359;

double  x = x1 | x2 | x3;  -->> The operator | is undefined for the argument type(s) doubel, double
```

I am wondering if there is a way to apply '|' to double numbers and get the result.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you imagine this operator would do?

Comment: "Just change the `|` to `+` will make your code compile." or "First cast x1, x2 and x3 to `long`". As long as you haven't explained what you expect the `|` operator to do with `double`, the only correct answer is @StinePike's - all the others are equally not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do bitwise arithmetic on `doubles` (although I can't imagine what use this would be), you can convert them to and from `long` using the methods `doubleToLongBits` and `longBitsToDouble` in the `Double` class.

So you could write

```
public static double bitwiseOr(double arg1, double arg2) {
    long long1 = Double.doubleToLongBits(arg1);
    long long2 = Double.doubleToLongBits(arg2);
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(long1 | long2);
}
```

but again, I don't see what possible application this has.

Answer (score 2):

The Java programming language only supports bitwise and bit shift operations on integral types. for more details see [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) here

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do it but you can use `Double.doubleToLongBits` to convert your double to long, do the bitwise OR and then convert result back to double using `Double.longBitsToDouble`